# Open partial view in pop-up window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, popup

I am trying to make a pop-up window open to display additionnal information to my users.

First of all, I'm kinda confused: what's the difference between **Modal** windows and **pop-up** windows?

Next, here's what I have done so far:

```
@Html.ActionLink(Model[i].mMasterItem.CARD_NAME, "SeeCardDetails", "Item", new { @_itemID = Model[i].mMasterItem.ITEM_LISTING_IDE }, new {@class = "modal"})
```

The `modal` class is merely a tag used in this action link to identify the link the call comes from.

Next, the controller partial view action:

```
public ActionResult SeeCardDetails(int? _itemID)
{
    if (_itemID == null)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }

    if (_itemID == 0)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }

    CardDisplay cardToShow = mCardManager.GetCardDisplayByID((int)_itemID);

    return PartialView(cardToShow);
}
```

And the partial view:

```
@model FinePlaySet.Utilities.CardDisplay

<p>This page shows!</p>
```

Nothing fancy, I'm just using this right now to build the frame.

And the jQuery/javascript/ajax/whatever try I made:

```
$('#dialog-modal').dialog({
   autoOpen: false,
    width: 400,
    resizable: false,
    modal:true
});

$('.modal').click(function() {
    $('#dialog-modal').load(this.href, function() {
        $(this).dialog('open');
    });
    return false;
});
```

And, lastly, I think I had to include a div which job is to actually open the pop-up / modal:

```
<div id="dialog-modal" title="See Card Detail"></div>
```

This `div` is located in my `Layout` page, so it's always there. Now I'm confused between all the tries I have made and all the stuff I have read and I need help: the basic need is only that **when a user clicks a link, a `CardDisplay` item is loaded and then showed in a pop-up window.** Can anyone help me out? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A modal window is loaded via javascript in the same page. If you want to open a new browser window or tab (popup window) you should add the atribute type="_blank" in your link (no javascript needed).

```
<a href="popoup_url" target="_blank">Open popup</a>
```

Comment: Wow! It's not perfect, but it DOES show the result on another page! Thanks, I feel like I just made a huge step! Now why do I need to make a blank target?

Comment: the atribute target is used to tell the browser how to open a link. take a look at w3schools:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp